# sessionStorage and sticky sessions

Tags: javascript, session, session-state, web-frontend

I was looking for some clarification really. Looking at the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) documentation on `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`, they write:

*Local storage is per origin (per domain and protocol). All pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data.*

Does this mean that if I have multiple web front ends, and my load balancer is **not** using sticky sessions, that the data I store with the `sessionStorage` object may not be accessible, dependent upon which WFE serves the data?

Just a little unclear, and it's difficult to test. Many thanks!

Comment: But your web page must be served on the single domain right ?

Comment: Single domain, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) are both stored in the *browser*, so your load balancer, sticky sessions, etc. will not affect these at all. They *may* affect any data you store in the session on your server though.

The difference between localStorage and sessionStorage is that sessionStorage is stored cleared when the page session ends, whereas localStorage has no expiration set.

Comment: Sorry, not quite there: "any data you store in the session on your server". Meaning any data I store pertaining to the session, on the server? rather than the client?

Comment: @GeorgeGrainger Yes. So any server-side session storage you use may be affected by load balancing, etc. Anything you do using JavaScript via window.sessionStorage or window.localStorage stores data in the user's browser only: this doesn't get stored on the server, so shouldn't be affected by load balancing.